# `dmap_if` and 'model.matrix' together

Tags: r, do.call, model.matrix, purrr, one-hot-encoding

I am using `Arthritis` data set from `vcd` package to perform one hot encoding. I would like to use`purrr::dmap_if` and `Matrix::model.matrix` together to to do this. When I run

```
do.call(model.matrix, list(Improved~.,Arthritis))
```

working fine.

When I use below code is not working

```
Arthritis %>% dmap_if(is.factor, do.call(model.matrix, list(Improved~., .)))
```

Comment: How about `keep` and `invoke` instead of `dmap_if`? `Arthritis %>% keep(is.factor) %>% invoke(model.matrix, Improved~., data = .)`.  The `invoke` function is just a wrapper around `do.call` to make it easy to use in a pipe.

Comment: Thank you, could you help me on how to get all levels, without having an intercept. It is dropping one level for each variable.

Comment: You can remove the intercept using `-1` in the formula of `model.matrix`.  However, that likely is still not quite what you want.  You might ask a new question specifically about how to get what you want out of `model.matrix` (or, more generally, a question about what result you need and why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, `dmap_if` goes through the columns of the dataset one a time and so doesn't necessarily seem like the right tool for this task.

If you want to use only the factor variables before applying a function, consider `keep`.  Once you've selected just the factor variables using `keep` you can use `invoke` to apply `model.matrix`.  The `invoke` function is just a wrapper for `do.call` that works nicely with pipes.

```
Arthritis %>% 
    keep(is.factor) %>% 
    invoke(model.matrix, Improved~., data = .)

   (Intercept) TreatmentTreated SexMale
1            1                1       1
2            1                1       1
3            1                1       1
4            1                1       1
5            1                1       1
6            1                1       1
7            1                1       1
8            1                1       1
9            1                1       1
10           1                1       1
11           1                1       1
12           1                1       1
13           1                1       1
14           1                1       1
15           1                1       0
16           1                1       0
...
```